# Generating PDF using sidekiq, wicked_pdf and haml rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf, haml, wicked-pdf

So I am trying to generate a PDF in the background with Sidekiq. I have followed the directions on their wiki but I keep running into a haml formatting error. When I generate the same pdf template through normal methods I do not get any of these haml formatting errors and the pdf generates fine. I am sure I'm missing something simple but, I just can't figure out what. Code below:

Worker Code:

```
class GeneratePdf
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(id)
    @report = Report.find(id)

    av = ActionView::Base.new()
    av.view_paths = ActionController::Base.view_paths

    av.class_eval do
      include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
      include ApplicationHelper
    end

    pdf = av.render template: 'quarterly_reports/show.pdf.haml',
    locals: {@report => @report}

    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
      pdf,
      header: {spacing: 10, html: {template: 'shared/qheader'}},
      footer: {spacing: 10, html: {template: 'shared/qfooter'}}
    )
    save_path = Rails.root.join('public', "PDF-{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d')}.pdf")
    File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
      file << pdf
    end
  end
end
```

So when the job fires Sidekiq spits out a formatting error from the second line of the page which is the following:

```
= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application"
= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "application", "jquery_nested_form", "chartkick"
```

After this it shows formatting issues which almost every line of haml in the view. It does not show issues with the first line of the code which is the stylesheet link shown above. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

show.pdf.haml

```
= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application"
= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "application", "jquery_nested_form", "chartkick"
- @page_title = "Report"
%meta{"http-equiv" => "content-type", "content" => "text/html", "charset" => "utf-8"}
%br
%br
%br
%br
%h2{align: "center"}
    Report
    %br
```

errors from sidekiq:

```
2016-03-16T16:29:06.488Z 22864 TID-ousqdbkxk WARN: SyntaxError: /Users/user/Sites/cp_reports/app/views/quarterly_reports/show.pdf.haml:2: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
));}\n#{_hamlout.format_script...
 ^
/Users/user/Sites/cp_reports/app/views/quarterly_reports/show.pdf.haml:3: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end
));}\n", 0, false); @page_title = "Report"
                                         ^
/Users/user/Sites/cp_reports/app/views/quarterly_reports/show.pdf.haml:4: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...amlout.push_text("<meta charset='utf-8' content='text/html' ...
...                               ^
/Users/user/Sites/cp_reports/app/views/quarterly_reports/show.pdf.haml:4: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
...("<meta charset='utf-8' content='text/html' http-equiv='cont...
...                               ^
/Users/user/Sites/cp_reports/app/views/quarterly_reports/show.pdf.haml:4: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
...utf-8' content='text/html' http-equiv='content-type'>\n<br>\...
...                               ^
/Users/user/Sites/cp_reports/app/views/quarterly_reports/show.pdf.haml:4: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
...ml' http-equiv='content-type'>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<h2#{
...                               ^
/Users/user/Sites/cp_reports/app/views/quarterly_reports/show.pdf.haml:4: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
...tp-equiv='content-type'>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<h2#{
...                               ^
/Users/user/Sites/cp_reports/app/views/quarterly_reports/show.pdf.haml:4: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
...iv='content-type'>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<h2#{
...                               ^
/Users/user/Sites/cp_reports/app/views/quarterly_reports/show.pdf.haml:4: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
...ntent-type'>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<h2#{
...                               ^
/Users/user/Sites/cp_reports/app/views/quarterly_reports/show.pdf.haml:4: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
...type'>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<h2#{
...                               ^
/Users/user/Sites/cp_reports/app/views/quarterly_reports/show.pdf.haml:9: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
...utes({}, nil, align: "center")}>\n  Report\n  <br>\n</h2>\n"...
...                               ^
/Users/user/Sites/cp_reports/app/views/quarterly_reports/show.pdf.haml:9: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
... "center")}>\n  Report\n  <br>\n</h2>\n", 0, false);::Haml::...
...                               ^
/Users/user/Sites/cp_reports/app/views/quarterly_reports/show.pdf.haml:9: unterminated regexp meets end of file
/Users/user/Sites/cp_reports/app/views/quarterly_reports/show.pdf.haml:9: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
2016-03-16T16:29:06.489Z 22864 TID-ousqdbkxk WARN: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/template.rb:297:in `module_eval'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/template.rb:297:in `compile'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/template.rb:245:in `block (2 levels) in compile!'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/template.rb:244:in `block in compile!'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/template.rb:232:in `synchronize'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/template.rb:232:in `compile!'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block in render_template'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.1.10/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/haml-4.0.7/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:12:in `render_with_haml'
/Users/user/Sites/cp_reports/app/workers/generate_pdf.rb:33:in `perform'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:150:in `execute_job'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:132:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:127:in `block in invoke'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6:in `call'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:74:in `call'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in `block in call'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:30:in `with_context'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:132:in `call'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:132:in `invoke'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:127:in `block in process'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:166:in `stats'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:126:in `process'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:79:in `process_one'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:67:in `run'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:16:in `watchdog'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sidekiq-4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:24:in `block in safe_thread'
```

Comment: Post the error message and the haml file please.

Comment: added content as requested

Answer (score 0):

After stepping through the render via cli. I noticed that the error had nothing to do with haml after all. When I was calling locals in render I had my symbol wrong. I changed this:

```
pdf = av.render template: 'quarterly_reports/show.pdf.haml',
locals: {@report => @report}
```

To This:

```
pdf = av.render template: 'quarterly_reports/show.pdf.haml',
locals: {:@report => @report}
```

Everything is now working as expected.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `{:@report => @report}` im not 100% sure what it does. At first glance I would imagine it would call `to_s` on report, then use that as the key. Which another developer looking at would assume(or at least be very confused). Use `{:report => @report}` instead. or the ruby 2 syntax: `{report: => @report}`.

Comment: I don't see how that really matters. My objects in the show.pdf.haml file are using @report instead of report. This is why I needed to use :@report for locals.